# Ignoring generated protobuf files in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, ide, protocol-buffers

I want my IDE to stop showing me the unreadable generated files when I search. Say I have a protobuf file `foo.proto` :

```
message bar {}
```

and I generate the python package `foo_pb2.py` (and the `foo_pb2.pyi`). When searching (double up arrow button/shift) for foo I'd like to see the protobuf definition in `foo.proto` but not the generated code in `foo_pb2.py`.

I managed to get the first thing to work by installing the "Protobuf Support" addon but I cannot find anything for the second part.

Similarly, when using the "Declaration" functionality (cmnd + click) I get sent to `foo_pb2.py` file instead of `foo.proto`. Is there a way to map these correctly?

Answer (score 1):

One way to ignore them is to basically put them in an `excluded` folder. PyCharm will exclude these folders entirely.

[image]

Comment: I'd prefer to not change the folder structure. It is a part of a bigger project with other people working on it.

Comment: I mean, you can ignore the excluded folder, and when it is time to commit, just move the .proto files to the right place.